# Problem when checking if a data is null in a database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, html, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a problem. I have a form on a page, which receives in a text input the code of a subject, at the time of making the corresponding checks, one of them gives a false result.

In the monitorings controller:

```
def inscribir
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])

    grupoDisponible = Student.buscarMateriaDisponible(params[:student_id],params[:codigo_materia])
    vioMateria = Student.vioCurso(params[:student_id], params[:codigo_materia])
    cumplePromedio = Student.calcPromedio(params[:student_id])
    creditos = Student.calc_credits(params[:student_id])

    @mensaje = "No se pudo asignar monitor a esa materia.\nRazon: "
    @todoBien = true
    if !grupoDisponible
        @todoBien = false
        @mensaje = @mensaje + "El grupo ya tiene monitor disponible."
        puts "El grupo ya tiene monitor disponible."
    end
    if !vioMateria
        @todoBien = false
        @mensaje = @mensaje + "El estudiante no ha visto la materia aun"
        puts "El estudiante no ha visto la materia aun"
    end
    if !cumplePromedio
        @todoBien = false
        @mensaje = @mensaje + "El estudiante no cumple el promedio requerido ser monitor"
        puts "El estudiante no cumple el promedio requerido ser monitor"
    end
    if creditos < 22
        @todoBien = false
        @mensaje = @mensaje + "El estudiante no cumple con los minimos creditos vistos."
        puts "El estudiante no cumple con los minimos creditos vistos."
    end
    if @todoBien
        @mensaje = Student.ingresarMonitoria(params[:student_id], params[:codigo_materia])
        puts @mensaje
    end
end
```

vioMateria always stores the false value, that is, the function vioCourse always returns false.

Function vioCourse (In model):

```
def self.vioCurso(id_student, cod_subject)

    puts id_student
    puts cod_subject
    logs = Student.find(id_student).logs
    encontrado = false
    logs.each do |log|
        codigo = Subject.find(log.subject_id).codigo
        if codigo == cod_subject
            encontrado = true
        end
    end
    return encontrado
end
```

The logic of the method is fine, since I have tried the logic in the rails console, replacing the variables with existing values, in this it is executed, but in the web page, not always giving false, moreover, when I enter this page, always the whole code is executed, when boy to button always gives false, the input parameters are fine.

Existing data in the different tables of the database:

SHELL:

```
Started POST "/students/1/monitorings/inscribir" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-10-07 02:57:56 -0500
Processing by MonitoringsController#inscribir as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+6Shqw+1nRkPnPt+ag/51tuJoVsH35Zip4fvsyR5FbCYjAdjECWrN56OOOb2iK5f+yyv8VhCIhYIZOp7IE7lMA==", "codigo_materia"=>"1256", "commit"=>"Buscar", "student_id"=>"1"}
  Student Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "subjects" WHERE "subjects"."student_id" = ? AND "subjects"."codigo" = ?  [["student_id", 1], ["codigo", 1256]]
1
1256
  CACHE Student Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Log Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "logs".* FROM "logs" WHERE "logs"."student_id" = ?  [["student_id", 1]]
  Subject Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "subjects".* FROM "subjects" WHERE "subjects"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Subject Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "subjects".* FROM "subjects" WHERE "subjects"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Subject Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "subjects".* FROM "subjects" WHERE "subjects"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Subject Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subjects".* FROM "subjects" WHERE "subjects"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Student Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Student Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Log Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "logs".* FROM "logs" WHERE "logs"."student_id" = ?  [["student_id", 1]]
  CACHE Subject Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subjects".* FROM "subjects" WHERE "subjects"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Subject Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subjects".* FROM "subjects" WHERE "subjects"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Subject Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subjects".* FROM "subjects" WHERE "subjects"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Subject Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "subjects".* FROM "subjects" WHERE "subjects"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
El estudiante no ha visto la materia aun
  Rendering monitorings/inscribir.html.erb within layouts/students
  Rendered students/_infoest.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered monitorings/_inscripcion.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered monitorings/inscribir.html.erb within layouts/students (40.9ms)
  Student Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."id" = ? ORDER BY "students"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered layouts/_menu.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 284ms (Views: 242.1ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)
```

HTML form code (in view):

```
<%= form_tag(inscribir_student_monitoring_post_path) do%>
    <%= text_field_tag 'codigo_materia', nil, placeholder: "Codigo de la materia", class: "EditBox", id: "EditboxCodigoMatInsMat"%>
    <hr id="LinSepComForm">

    <div id="wb_ButtonInsMatInsMat">
        <%= submit_tag "Buscar", id: "ButtonInsMatInsMat", class: "boton", style: "color: #FFFFFF"%> 
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't completely understand the code and am a bit lazy to figure out what it means. So when working with other developers, using english variables is a big help ;)

Nonetheless, I thought it might be of interested to let you know of a better way to implement the `vioCurso` method which does not require loading the `Student`, all of their `logs` and `subjects`, directly asking the database to check whether the record exists.

```
def self.vioCurso(student_id, subject_code)
  Subject.joins(:log).merge(Log.where(student_id: student_id)).where(codigo: subject_code).exists?
end
```

You can even make this an ActiveRecord scope:

```
class Subject < ApplicationRecord
  scope :for_student_and_code, ->(student_id, subject_code) do
    joins(:log).merge(Log.where(student_id: student_id)).where(codigo: subject_code)
  end
end
```

and then do

```
Subject.for_student_and_code(student_id, subject_code).exists?
```

To learn more about the `joins` and `merge` methods, look at the corresponding API documentation: mastering those two can save you a lot of effort in all kinds of situations.

I realize that this might not answer your question but it was too long to put in a comment and properly format it, too...